# h1 on body is centered even when i float:left;

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, I don't know where is the mistake in my code.
So I have a class header-text to show "Welcome to MOK VPS" with h1.

I used `float:left;` on my CSS code but it stills show the text on the center. But if I use `float:right;` it moves to the right.

I'm just messing around with HTML and CSS after learning it a few hours and reviewing what I learned.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.header-home {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(23, 32, 42, 0.7);
  color: #CCD1D1;
}

.header-logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.header-list li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
}

.header-login {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  float: right;
}

.body-text {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class=header-home>
  <div class=header-logo>
    <h1>MOK VPS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=header-list>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Features</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class=header-login>
    <p>LOGIN</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=body>
  <div class=body-text>
    <h1>Welcome to MOK VPS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On my editor, it shows the text in the middle. I added margin-bottom:2px; on my header class and my text moved to left. I don't understand why, but it works. Maybe you know what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added borders around the elements to illustrate what is happening here. Click Run code snippet to see.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  /* adding for demonstration */
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header-home {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(23, 32, 42, 0.7);
  color: #CCD1D1;
}

.header-logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.header-list li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
}

.header-login {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  float: right;
}

.body-text {
  border-color: lime;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class=header-home>
  <div class=header-logo>
    <h1>MOK VPS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=header-list>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Features</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class=header-login>
    <p>LOGIN</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=body>
  <div class=body-text>
    <h1>Welcome to MOK VPS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you look closely, you'll see that the body-text div is actually caught on the header-home div. To prevent that, use `clear` to cause your div to go to the next line, after any previously `float`ed elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  /* adding for demonstration */
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header-home {
  height: 75px;
  background-color: rgba(23, 32, 42, 0.7);
  color: #CCD1D1;
}

.header-logo {
  float: left;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-right: 20%;
}

.header-list li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
}

.header-login {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-right: 45px;
  float: right;
}

.body-text {
  border-color: lime;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class=header-home>
  <div class=header-logo>
    <h1>MOK VPS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class=header-list>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Features</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class=header-login>
    <p>LOGIN</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class=body>
  <div class=body-text>
    <h1>Welcome to MOK VPS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change in your CSS for class body-text. "Absolute positioned" element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document body, and moves along with page scrolling.:

```
.body-text {
  position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add the position:absolute on your class body-text. Just add that get you problem fixed. But you also can make this:

```
.body-text {
    position: absolute;
    left: *****  Here you define how much you wanna move the tag, for example 20px***
  }
```

Comment: It actually works, but can you explain why my text is appearing on the center and why I need to use position:absolute?

Comment: This is actually a bad idea. This is treating the symptom, rather than the cause.

Comment: Because the property float used on the other elements pull the h1 to te center. Use position absolute references the position of the tag according with parent element, not the element on her on. If you define, for example top: 20px, it pull off the tag 20px down the father element. Use the position absolute is just only one of the many ways you can solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to style `<h1>`. Like `text-align: left;`.

```css
h1{
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block; /*use this code if needed. It can be replaced with text-align*/
}
```